# Cannot find 'Microsoft Azure Web Apps' in the list of publish targets in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my web application to Microsoft Azure Web Apps stack. For the same, what I do is, I right click on the project from visual studio 2015, click on publish, and find the 'Publish' window with the list of publish targets in the 'Profile' tab. But, I do not find 'Microsoft Azure Web Apps' option in the list of publish targets. What might be missing ? Please suggest.I have installed Microsoft Azure SDK version 2.9.6. There are newer versions available. Can this be a reason why the web apps option is not appearing ?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and fixed the issue by installing the latest updates for my Visual Studio and also updates for Windows OS. 
Do install the latest Azure SDK (Version 3.0) available and check to see if it helps. 
Download link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/